# How do I load a dropdown list in ASP.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I load a dropdown list in asp.net and c#?

Comment: [Already answered in many ways ...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18116273/2181188

Answer (score 9):

You can also do it declaratively:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="yourDDL">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Add something" Value="theValue" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You can also data bind them:

```
yourDDL.DataSource = YourIEnumberableObject;
yourDDL.DataBind();
```

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, you can also add items programatically:

```
yourDDL.Items.Add(YourSelectListItem);
```

Comment: you can also add programmatically myDropDownList.Items.Add( "stuff");

Answer (score 6):

using Gortok's example, you can databind the list to the dropdownlist also

```
List<Employee> ListOfEmployees = New List<Employees>();

DropDownList DropDownList1 = new DropDownList();

DropDownList1.DataSource = ListOfEmployees ;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "TextFieldToBeDisplayed";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ValueFieldForLookup";

DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

wow...rather quick to the point there...

`DropDownLists` have an items collection, you call the Add method of that collection.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add( "what you are adding" );
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have a collection of employee objects, you could add them like so:

```
List<Employee> ListOfEmployees = New List<Employees>();

DropDownList DropDownList1 = new DropDownList();

foreach (Employee employee in ListOfEmployees) {
DropDownList1.Items.Add(employee.Name);
}
```

Comment: Years later.. but why not just bind the List<Employee> directly to the list? No need to iterate through them. List<> already implements IEnumerable.

Comment: @user3308043 6 years ago, I had been using Webforms for a grand total of 4 months. There's a lot I'd do differently now.

Comment: I'm guessing that means MVC?