# What is the right way to populate a DropDownList from a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am populating a DropDownList from a SQL Server database as shown below. It works fine, but I'm not sure it's a good way. Can someone shed some light on this method, and give some improvements?

```
private void LoadSubjects()
{
    ddlSubjects.Items.Clear();
    string selectSQL = "SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName FROM Students.dbo.Subjects";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    SqlDataReader reader;

    try
    {
        ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
        newItem.Text = "<Select Subject>";
        newItem.Value = "0";
        ddlSubjects.Items.Add(newItem);

        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = reader["SubjectName"].ToString();
            newItem.Value = reader["SubjectID"].ToString();
            ddlSubjects.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        //TODO
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You could bind the DropDownList to a data source (DataTable, List, DataSet, SqlDataSource, etc).

For example, if you wanted to use a DataTable:

```
ddlSubject.DataSource = subjectsTable;
ddlSubject.DataTextField = "SubjectNamne";
ddlSubject.DataValueField = "SubjectID";
ddlSubject.DataBind();
```

**EDIT - More complete example**

```
private void LoadSubjects()
{

    DataTable subjects = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SubjectID, SubjectName FROM Students.dbo.Subjects", con);
            adapter.Fill(subjects);

            ddlSubject.DataSource = subjects;
            ddlSubject.DataTextField = "SubjectNamne";
            ddlSubject.DataValueField = "SubjectID";
            ddlSubject.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

    }

    // Add the initial item - you can add this even if the options from the
    // db were not successfully loaded
    ddlSubject.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("<Select Subject>", "0"));

}
```

To set an initial value via the markup, rather than code-behind, specify the option(s) and set the AppendDataBoundItems attribute to true:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubject" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="<Select Subject>" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You could then bind the DropDownList to a DataSource in the code-behind (just remember to remove:

```
ddlSubject.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("<Select Subject>", "0"));
```

from the code-behind, or you'll have two "" items.

Comment: This is a better way than adding items individually to the dropdownlist.

Comment: subjectsTable is a `DataTable`? How to fetch it from database? Do I need to iterate to create the datatable?

Comment: I need "<Select Subject>" as first entry. If I bind the control, how to take care of this?

Comment: @andromeda - yes, in my example subjectsTable is a DataTable.  I've updated my answer to include a complete example.

Comment: @andromeda - sorry, I missed that part.  I've updated the code example in my answer.  You can also add "static" options like that in the markdown if desired, just make sure you set the DropDownList's AppendDataBoundItems attribute to true.

Comment: Yes, because of the using statement.  See [using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: a good thing to do is also to get data separately from binding to dropdown. also moving it to another method returning DataTable/set and even to the data access component

Comment: What if I wanted to set it in ASCENDING order?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - User an `ORDER BY` clause on the query.  For example: `SELECT SubjectID, SubjectName FROM Students.dbo.Subjects ORDER BY SubjectName ASC` - this would order the result in ascending order by SubjectName.

Answer (score 15):

I hope I am not overstating the obvious, but why not do it directly in the ASP side? Unless you are dynamically altering the SQL based on certain conditions in your program, you should avoid codebehind as much as possible.

You could do the above all in ASP directly without code using the SqlDataSource control and a property in your dropdownlist.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSubjects" runat="server" DataKeyNames="SubjectID" OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView_DataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subjects">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubjects" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsSubjects" DataTextField="SubjectName" DataValueField="SubjectID">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsSubjects" runat="server"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName FROM Students.dbo.Subjects"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I feel like this is the "right way" to do it. I also had to specify the connection string, more info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1kdt8w2(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: In response to "why not do it directly in the ASP side?" One reason would be that you need your dropdown list to databind at a different time than the default. If DataSourceID is set, the databind happens after the PreRender event.

Comment: Isn't connecting to database without try/catch considered bad practice?

Comment: @Kajbo - not in this case. If you were mimicking the same logic above in C#, they yes, I agree with you - try/catch would be essential.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void getClientNameDropDowndata()
{
    getConnection = Connection.SetConnection(); // to connect with data base Configure manager
    string ClientName = "Select  ClientName from Client ";
    SqlCommand ClientNameCommand = new SqlCommand(ClientName, getConnection);
    ClientNameCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataReader ClientNameData;
    ClientNameData = ClientNameCommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (ClientNameData.HasRows)
    {
        DropDownList_ClientName.DataSource = ClientNameData;
        DropDownList_ClientName.DataValueField = "ClientName";
        DropDownList_ClientName.DataTextField="ClientName";
        DropDownList_ClientName.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No is found");
        CloseConnection = new Connection();
        CloseConnection.closeConnection(); // close the connection 
    }
}
```

Comment: any chance you can explain this code, so someone coming along later can learn why it is an answer to the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Enabled = false;
```