# method in c# to populate drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I need to create a code behind method in c# that will populate my drop down list on my ASP.NET page.  I am having trouble with going about this as I am very new to c#.  I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction.  Everything I have tried so far has not worked.  I appreciate and welcome any help or ideas.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227510/asp-net-right-way-to-populate-a-dropdown-list-from-database).

Comment: Please explain what makes you think that one more sample will help you to with this code - what did not work as you expected in particular implementations, what you already tried, ... So far your post contains what you want to do and a lot of "thank you"/"new here"/"searched a lot" text instead of information where you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Add DropDownList to Asp.Net Page and add following code.

```
yourDropDownList.DataSource = yourDataSource;
yourDropDownList.DataTextField = "YourTextField";
yourDropDownList.DataValueField = "YourValueField";
yourDropDownList.DataBind();
```

[DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to populate the dropdownlist (`System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList`). Couple of them are given below:

### Alternative 1:

suppose you have a list of strings and you want to insert them. You can do that by:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "A", "B"};
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.DataSource = list;
ddl.SelectedIndex = 0; // if u want to select the very 1st item by default
```

### Alternative 2:

suppose you have class like below:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Value { get; set;}
}
```

And you want to bind a list of `Test` objects to dropdownlist. You also want to display the `Name` property in the ddl, but want to get the corresponding `Value` property when a particular item is selected from ddl. Here is the way:

```
List<Test> tests = new List<Test>
                       {
                           new Test
                               {
                                   Name = "Test1",
                                   Value = 100
                               },
                           new Test
                               {
                                   Name = "Test2",
                                   Value = 80
                               }
                       }

DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.DataSource = list;
ddl.DataTextField = "Name"; // property u wanna display
ddl.DataValueField = "Value"; // property u wanna retrieve value from
ddl.DataBind();
ddl.SelectedIndex = 0; // if u want to select the very 1st item by default
```

Now its upto you to follow whichever fulfills your need. Good luck!

Comment: i have this in my code   List<string> list = new List<string> { "Month", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"};
       
        DropDownListMonth.DataSource = list;
        DropDownListMonth.DataBind();
        DropDownListMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
        foreach (ListItem item in DropDownListMonth.Items)
        {
               int i = 0;
               string month = Convert.ToString(i);
            DropDownListMonth.DataValueField = month;
            i = Convert.ToInt32(month);
            i++;
        }

Comment: i get an error though when ever I try to do anything on my page:        DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name '0'.

Comment: if i take out the fpr loop, when i try and select a value from the list, it doesn't change to that value

Comment: i have put your comments in your question

Comment: DropDownListMonth.DataValueField should only be set when the class of binded object has any property that you want to use as Value Field. In your case, you don't need DropDownListMonth.DataValueField as you have bound a `List<string>` where `string` class itself represents a value. So please refer to `ALTERNATIVE 1` in my answer.