# Compiler Error Message: CS1061:

Tags: asp.net

i have a drop-list that has to be showing image files names from a folder ,but when i run the page this error accrues:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.pagesnew_managementpages_manageproducts_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ddImage_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'ddImage_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.pagesnew_managementpages_manageproducts_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ManageProducts.aspx.cs" Inherits="PagesNew_ManagementPages_ManageProducts" %>
```

the tags that were wrong:

```
Image:</p>
Line 25:     <p>
Line 26:         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddImage" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddImage_SelectedIndexChanged">
Line 27:         </asp:DropDownList>
Line 28:     </p>
```

---

this is the whole file:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <p>
        Name:</p>
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p>
        Type:</p>
    <p>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddType" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductTypes] ORDER BY [Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </p>
    <p>
        Price:</p>
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p>
        Image:</p>
    <p>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddImage" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddImage_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </p>
    <p>
        Description:</p>
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Height="72px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

---

I don't understand whats wrong?

Comment: Did you ever define `ddImage_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: The error message can't be any clearer... If you reference an event handler in aspx file, you have to define it in code-behind.

Comment: yeah i just defined it in the code-behind, but my image names which  are the items for the drop list are not showing in the drop-list!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, select the dropdown, go to its properties, hit events and double click where it says onSelectedindexChanged, VS will create the definition of the event and direct you to its cursor.

Just write a simple code line inside and see if it compiles.

If you already have done this, put a break point on the event, enable exceptions thrown from tools, and run through the event, it should give you a more elaborate message as to why it failed.

Comment: yeah i just defined it in the code-behind, but my image names which  are the items for the drop list are not showing in the drop-list!!!  @John Saunders        the output is empty drop-list!  what is wrong?

Comment: yeah i just defined it in the code-behind, but my image names which  are the items for the drop list are not showing in the drop-list!!!    @walther          the output is empty drop-list!  what is wrong?

Comment: yeah i just defined it in the code-behind, but my image names which  are the items for the drop list are not showing in the drop-list!!!     @YankTHEcode          the output is empty drop-list!  what is wrong?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227510/asp-net-right-way-to-populate-a-dropdown-list-from-database  This will provide you a good way to hook up everything. I strongly suggest reading some tutorials on controls on and databinding. :)