# fill dropdownlist from onselectindexchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

im using asp.net and c#

im using 2 dropdownlist like dd1,dd2

how to fill 2nd dropdownlist dd2 by dd1 onselectindexchanged

my code is,

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddMedType" runat="server" CssClass="drop" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddMedType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Tablet">Tablet</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Tonic">Tonic</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Capsules">Capsules</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="DispoTab">Disposable Tablet</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddMedName" runat="server" CssClass="drop" >
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>


protected void ddMedType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MedType = ddMedType.SelectedItem.Text;
        string str = "select MedicineName,MedicineId from MedicineMaster where MedicineType = '" + MedType + "'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

             ddMedName.SelectedValue= reader["MedicineId"].ToString();


        }
    }
```

here the condition returns 2 items, but dropdownlist dd2 returns only 1 ...

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227510/what-is-the-right-way-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-from-a-database

Comment: You can't add items in dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the SelectedValue, this does not mean you're adding or removing items in your dropdownlist

```
DataTable medicines= new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select MedicineName,MedicineId from MedicineMaster where MedicineType = '" + MedType + "'", con);
        adapter.Fill(subjects);

        ddMedName.DataSource = subjects;
        ddMedName.DataTextField = "MedicineName";
        ddMedName.DataValueField = "MedicineId";
        ddMedName.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the error
    }

}

// Add the initial item - you can add this even if the options from the
// db were not successfully loaded
ddMedName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select-", "0"));
```

You can also do it with the reader as follows:

```
ddMedName.Items.Clear();
ddMedName.Items.Add(new ListItem("-Select-", "0"));
while (reader.Read())
{
  ddMedName.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader["MedicineName"].ToString(), reader["MedicineId"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add item in the DropdownList..

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader["MedicineId"].ToString(), reader["MedicineId"].ToString()));
```

Comment: it means your database returnig query repeated values so check data base query and make sure it should not return repeated value

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution may help you:

```
protected void ddMedType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string MedType = ddMedType.SelectedItem.Text;
            string str = "select MedicineName,MedicineId from MedicineMaster where MedicineType = '" + MedType + "'";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddMedName.DataSource = reader;
            ddMedName.DataTextField = "MedicineName";
            ddMedName.DataValueField = "MedicineId";
            ddMedName.DataBind();
        }
```