# How to load database content to dynamic TextBox when an item is selected from dynamic DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, event-handling, dynamically-generated

This is my interface, all the asp elements displayed are dynamically created! (Except the header)
[image]

**Things I perform dynamically:**
1. Create row with all those asp elements when page loads or button clicked.
2. I am able to lo populate `DropDownList` in "Items" column from database when it is created dynamically.

**What I want to achieve?:**
I want to load 'item code' 'item price' to appropriate text box when the item is selected from the `DropDownList`.
(Ex: when I click Laptop; it should load its item code and unit price to appropriate text box)
(Sorry for my bad programming approach, I'm beginner to asp.net)

```
'Page Load function'
Protected Sub     Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If Not Page.IsPostBack or Page.IsPostBack Then
    GenerateRows(numRows)   'Creates dynamic Table row and column with TextBox and DropDownList'
End If
End Sub

'Dynamic generating function, i have trimmed the code, to make it simple'
Protected Sub GenerateRows(numRows As Integer)
For i = 0 To numRows
        Dim tRow As New TableRow
        Dim tCode As New TableCell
        Dim tItem As New TableCell

        Dim lCode As New TextBox
        Dim dList As New DropDownList

        con = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=DataStore;Integrated Security=True")
        con.Open()
        query = "Select Item_Desc from Product"
        cmd = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dList.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dList.DataTextField = "Item_Desc"
        dList.DataBind()
        dList.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--- Select Product ---"))
        dList.Height = 30
        dList.AutoPostBack = True
        dList.CausesValidation = True
        AddHandler dList.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Dynamic_Method
        con.Close()

        tCode.Controls.Add(lCode)
        tItem.Controls.Add(dList)

        tRow.Cells.Add(tCode)
        tRow.Cells.Add(tItem)

        Table1.Rows.Add(tRow) 'Table1 is not dynamic element'
    Next
    numRows += 1
    ViewState("RowCount") = numRows 'numRows is Global variable'
End Sub

'This function is called when the selected index of DropDownList changes'
Protected Sub Dynamic_Method(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    con = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=DataStore;Integrated Security=True")
    con.Open()
    Dim DDL As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
    query = "Select * from Product where Item_Desc='" & DDL.SelectedValue.ToString & "'"  
    cmd = New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows = True Then
        While (dr.Read)
            ic = dr(0) 'dr(0) contains Item code of selected value which i need to add to textbox'
        End While
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to identify your item (record Id). In drop down, this id should be the value. So, when you select item in drop down, you use that Id to get record in DB and show fields in your controls

Comment: Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7227536/1704458 And then do this `"Select x , y, z from Product where Item_ID = " & DDL.SelectedValue`. Better yet `"....Item_ID = @1` and add parameter. --> Not `While`, `If`--> `If reader.Read() Then x=reader("x") y=reader("y") z=reader("z")`

Comment: The solution what you have provided is already there in my program. I think you need to see what i want to achieve!

Comment: Absolutely NOT! I mean, solution I pointed you to is NOT what you have. And your troubles root in that fact. For example, where you have `"Select Item_Desc from Product"`, you should have `"Select Id, Item_Desc from Product"`

Comment: When my query is `Select * from  Products where Item_Desc='’` it should contain everything. As i mentioned, i can obtain the id from database but i don't know how to add that value into texbox.  (How i can refer that particular textbox form this method?)