# Database access from within asp.net C# web sitie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net web site I'm trying to develop and I have an issue loading data from a database.  It worked fine in a C# WebForm App and I was wondering what i need to do to get it to work correctly in the asp.net project and bind the results to a dropdownlist to be selected from.

```
try
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    DataSource = "127.0.0.1",
                    InitialCatalog = "PIIMSDATA",
                    IntegratedSecurity = true
                };
        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Book1 Order by ID", cs);


                }
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                //DropDownList2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                //DropDownList2.DataTextField = "ID";
                //DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ID";
                //DropDownList2.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + ex + "');", true);
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: after I uncomment the DropDownList code it never populates with my database results

Comment: Do you get an error of some sort? Try debugging the code line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. Here's an example that I've ever tried:

```
    public string connectionString = "Data Source = YOUCANSEEONSQLSERVER; Initial Catalog = DATABASENAME; User Id = sa; Password = sqlpasswordifyouuse";

    private void Valetin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OPIDCB.ResetText();
        ValetCB.ResetText();
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(pr.connectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlselect1 = new SqlCommand("Select EmpID, EmpName from Employees.Employee where IDPosition = 'OP'", sqlconn);
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr1 = sqlselect1.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            ArrayList MyAL = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList MyAL2 = new ArrayList();
            MyAL.Add(dr1.GetString(0));
            MyAL2.Add(dr1.GetString(1));
            foreach (string s in MyAL)
                foreach (string s2 in MyAL2)
                {
                    OPIDCB.Items.Add(s + " " + s2);
                }
            OPIDCB.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        dr1.Close();
        sqlconn.Close();

    }
```

If you are confusing with that code, you can visit this link: [What is the right way to populate a DropDownList from a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227510/what-is-the-right-way-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-from-a-database)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create connection string in web.config and get this param to bind in dropdownlist

Try to this link :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/binding-dropdownlist-with-database-and-display-data-in-gridv/