# How to fill a dropdownlist with arraylist that I get from a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dropdown

I am consuming a java web service in asp.net, the method is an arraylist that devuleve the code and name, and I do not know how to load it to a dropdonwlist in which it shows the name and value is the code.

I tried the following way:

```
WebReferences.agencia datos = new WebReferences.agencia();

listAgencia.DataSource = datos;
listAgencia.DataTextField = datos.nombre;
listAgencia.DataValueField = Convert.ToString(datos.ida);
listAgencia.DataBind();
```

It gives me error in the datasource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to populate a DropDownList from a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227510/what-is-the-right-way-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-from-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

As you access properties **nombre** and **ida** from **datos**, it seems that **datos** isn't a collection but a single object.

In this case this would be enough:

```
listaAgencia.Items.Add(new ListItem(datos.nombre, datos.ida.ToString()));
```

Should **datos** be a collection, instead, I would do like this:

```
foreach (var singleData in datos)
   listaAgencia.Items.Add(new ListItem(singleData.nombre, singleData.ida.ToString()));
```